# How to create SEO friendly links in MVC using ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo

I'm wondering how I can make ActionLink method create a link that generates something like:

```
/Home/Search/canon
```

instead of

```
/Home/Search?q=canon
```

If ActionLink cannot do that, has anybody ever done this by other means?

Comment: Please read the question. Maybe it's not what you think!

Comment: People might get confused because of the title...

Comment: Can you share the code you use for creating the ActionLink?

Comment: Sure. What I've used is `@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Home", new { q = something })`

Answer (score 1):

define a new route in your global.ascx

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route
{
url="[controller]/[action]/[q]",
Defaultd=new{ action="Index", q=(string) null},
RouteHandler=typeof(MvcRouteHandler)

});
```

and your ActionLink would map to it just fine

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Home", new { q = something })
```

would produce

```
/Home/Search/something
```

[*here*](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) is a useful link